# Rails update_attributes for a specific associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, updates, accepts-nested-attributes

I have the following setup:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, inverse_of: :post, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
end
```

If I call `post.update_attributes(post_params)`

Where `post_params` is the following:

```
post_params = {
  "content"=>"Post something",
  "comments_attributes"=>{
    "0"=>{
      "content"=>"comment on something"
    }
  }
}
```

A comment new comments is created and associated with the post.

Is there a way to us update_attributes on the post and still update a specific comment associated with the post?

Maybe something like:

```
post_params = {
  "content"=>"Post something",
  "comments_attributes"=>{
    "0"=>{
      "id"=>"1", #if the id exist update that comment, if not then add a new comment.
      "content"=>"comment on something"
    }
  }
}
```

So then I can call `post.update_attributes(post_params)` and take advantage of the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` on updates.

If this is not possible, what is the a best way to do an update of post with an update of an associated comment?

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update the provided records so long as you maintain the correct model ID for the model.

So if `post` has `comments` with IDs 4,5,6, you can submit:

```
post.update(comments_attributes: [{id: 4, content: 'bob'}]
```

And that will update the existing `Comments.find(4)` record (provided it validates successfully).

But if you were to pass an ID that did not apply to the comments that belongs to that post an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Thanks!  So it looks like there was something what I wrote in my question.  When I tried something like that it did not work.  But it turned out I did not set the id in my Strong Params.  Thanks again. :-)